# How to display multiple codes from a Code_Master table based on the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Code_Master table which has 3000+ codes. These codes are embedded in all of my tables, but as different column names...

Example: I have a table called Notes which houses incoming call notes for all student accounts (All Student Acct info is held in table: CA_Prof). I have 3 columns in this table which display codes from the Code_Master table. I have a Note_Category column (Codes 1-5), a Caller_Mood column (Codes 6-10) and a Caller column (Codes 11-15).

In the CA_Prof table I have a column named C_ID (Student Acct #) and CA_Id (Sub Account (Is this their first, second, third acct, etc). I also have a column S_Id (School ID# for the school they attend)

I want to be able to display:

Note_Category, Code_Description (from Code_Master), Caller_Mood, Code_Description (from Code_Master), Caller, Code_Description (from Code_Master)

but only for records that the C_ID and CA_ID found in Notes records match the C_Id and CA_Id from CA_Prof

I can't figure how to do this with the different columns using codes from the same Code_Master table.

Here is what I have:

```
    SELECT
    can.C_Id,
    can.CA_Id,
    can.Note_No,
    can.Caller_Mood,
    cm.Code_Desc,
    can.Caller,
    can.Note_Category,
    can.How_Contacted_Code,
    can.Note,
    can.Insert_Time,
    can.Insert_User
FROM Notes can (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN CA_Prof cap
    ON can.C_Id = cap.C_Id
    AND can.CA_Id = cap.CA_Id
Inner Join Code_Mstr cm on can.Caller_Mood=cm.Code_Id 
WHERE cap.S_Id = 8027
    AND can.Insert_Time >= '05/01/2014'
    AND can.Insert_Time <= '01/01/2015'
    AND can.How_Contacted_Code = '331'
ORDER BY can.Note_Cat_Code ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to the same table more than once. I think you want something like this:

```
select
    ...
    n.Note_Category
    nc.Code_Description as Note_Category_Description,
    ...
    n.Caller_Mood,
    cm.Code_Description as Caller_Mood_Description,
    ...
from Notes n
join Code_Master nc on nc.Code_Id = n.Note_Category
join Code_Master cm on cm.Code_Id = n.Caller_Mood
...
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you. I did not realize I could Join to the same table multiple times with different aliases. Can I also do this for different types of Joins? Say Inner and Left?

Comment: Yes, you can. Note that `inner join` means the same as just `join`. By the way, if this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark to the left of it.